# Conditional statement in sql query on classic ASP Page

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I am fetching three values in my page named 123.asp
`(123.asp?School=NewEnglishSchool&Batch=1&AcademicYear=2)`

```
School = Request.QueryString("School")
Batch = Request.QueryString("Batch")
AcademicYear = Request.QueryString("AcademicYear")
```

I have a simple query in form like below
strSqlData="select * from MyTable where gender="male""

I need to create a query like below, if I found a value for Batch and AcademicYear except for School on the page via `Request.QueryString means (123.asp?Batch=1&AcademicYear=2)`

then I want to write a query something like this

```
strSqlData="select * from MyTable where gender="male" 
if len(AcademicYear)<>o then 
and AcademicYear='"&AcademicYear&"'

elseif len(Batch)<>o then 
and Batch='"&Batch&"'
end if  

elseif len(School)<>o then 
and School='"&School&"'
end if  "
```

I want to create something like above but in proper method without using case, because I have so many filters on the page like school, batch and Academicyear.

Comment: why not use store procedure instead of sql query.

Comment: This is a typical catch-all query. You can read about how to solve this type of thing quite nicely here. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ No matter what you decide you desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript you can use the ampersand (&) symbol to concatenate strings. Try this:

```
strSqlData="select * from MyTable where gender='male'" 

if AcademicYear <> "" then 
strSqlData= strSqlData & " and AcademicYear=" & AcademicYear
end if

if Batch <> "" then
strSqlData= strSqlData & " and Batch=" & Batch    
end if  

if School <> "" then 
strSqlData= strSqlData & " and School=" & School
end if
```

You have three separate "and" clauses to append to your sql query.  The conditional statements are independent of each other so you shouldn't be using `elseif` which is for different options within a single conditional statement.  It's simpler to check whether or not a string isn't empty `if stringname <> ""` than using `len`, (and I doubt your conditional statements would work because you appear to be using a lower case letter "o" where you should be using a zero)

It's very easy to make mistakes when you're assembling sql queries like this.  In testing it's often worth adding a line like `Response.Write strSqlData` before you try to execute it to check that the query is what you were intending

As other comments have suggested though, your code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. Urls which contain ".asp?" can almost be guaranteed to be hit by an ASPROX type attack sooner or later. Parameterised queries are the best means of guarding against this, but one quick approach if your querystring values are all numeric is to use `cint()` - eg

```
strSqlData= strSqlData & " and AcademicYear=" & cint(AcademicYear)
```

This will throw a type mismatch error if the querystring contains anything other than numbers, and the script will fall over before it attempts to execute your sql query.

Comment: Worth to mention the risk of SQL Injection attacks here, and even better use parameters.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I think I did say all of that in my penultimate paragraph.  I think parameterised queries might look a little bit daunting to someone without much experience of Classic ASP though, and `cint()` can be a useful quick fix, although it can't be applied to all scenarios

Comment: Heh, you're right. Maybe  just move this on top so it will be more visible... anyway, well done!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a sql query in your asp page you may create a Store Procedure and call it on your ASP page with the required parameter from your Query String.

Here is the sample SP which I have created as per your asked scenario

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_fetch_data @school       VARCHAR(max), 
                               @batch        VARCHAR(max), 
                               @academicYear VARCHAR(max) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET @school = (SELECT CASE 
                              WHEN @school = '' THEN NULL 
                              ELSE @school 
                            END) 
      SET @batch = (SELECT CASE 
                             WHEN @batch = '' THEN NULL 
                             ELSE @batch 
                           END) 
      SET @academicYear = (SELECT CASE 
                                    WHEN @academicYear = '' THEN NULL 
                                    ELSE @academicYear 
                                  END) 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   mytable 
      WHERE  gender = 'male' 
             AND school = @school 
             AND batch = @batch 
             AND academicyear = @academicYear 
  END
```

Now simply call this SP in your ASP page:

```
strSqlData = "sp_fetch_data'"&Request.QueryString("school")&"','"&Request.QueryString("batch")&"','"&Request.QueryString("academicYear")&"'"
```

EDIT:Execute Store Procedure with NULL data

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Sp_fetch_data @school       VARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                              @batch        VARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                              @academicYear VARCHAR(max) = NULL 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   mytable 
      WHERE  gender = 'male' 
             AND ( @school = school 
                    OR @school IS NULL ) 
             AND ( @batch = batch 
                    OR @batch IS NULL ) 
             AND ( @academicYear = academicyear 
                    OR @academicYear IS NULL ) 
  END
```

Comment: Not my own, but guess because you're making things more complicated for no real gain.

Comment: If the solution resolved your problem you can give an upvote to this.

Comment: I don't think either of your options is actually doing what most people would want. E.g. if I specify a school and batch but leave the academic year blank, I expect to get records in that school and batch, but from *all* academic years, whether 2017/2018, 1998/99, NULL, blank string, or anything else. If I'm interpreting things correctly, both versions of your code would return only those records where the academic year is NULL.

Answer (score -3):

You should think the problem only as a string creation. You have to create a string that will be a correct sql query. 
The approach that you have tried wants to create a query that contains logical statements. Instead of that, you should write your C# code in a way to create a proper sql query.

For an example, let's take the first part of your query:

```
strSqlData="select * from MyTable where gender="male" 
if len(AcademicYear)<>o then 
and AcademicYear='"&AcademicYear&"'
```

You can easily transfer that for a proper C# solution something like that:

```
    string strSqlData;
    int AcademicYear = 1994;
    int o = 2000;
    string male = "male";

    strSqlData="select * from MyTable where gender= " + male;

    if (AcademicYear != o)
        strSqlData += " and AcademicYear=" + AcademicYear.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(strSqlData);
```

Actually after you have fixed that part of your code, there will be some additional to do that you have to do. For example, your should use parametrized queries instead of hard coding an sql string.
Maybe you should find an example about building data access layer.

Comment: This is Classic ASP.  C# code is of no use whatsoever.

Comment: Not only is this the wrong language but building up a string like this and executing it is perpetuating the problem of sql injection.